# Can't fix Concurrency Violation VB/Access Database

Tags: vb.net

Cannot figure out how to resolve this issue. If I add rows to the database and close the form and then open the form an remove rows, I get no issues. The issue only arises when I add rows and remove rows without closing the form. What happens when the form closes that doesn't happen when the form is open?

If a box is checked, it gets added to the database. If a box gets unchecked it gets removed.

Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

---

```
Private Sub CreateNewDataRow(intNewTreeView As Integer, intNewUserID As Integer)

        Dim tvGeneric As Windows.Forms.TreeView
        Dim intTopic As Integer

        tvGeneric = GetTreeView(intNewTreeView)
        intTopic = intNewTreeView

        Try
            ' Loop through tabs to get checked items
            For x As Integer = 0 To tvGeneric.Nodes.Count - 1
                If tvGeneric.Nodes(x).Checked = True Then
                    Dim drNewRow As MasterDBDataSet.DBAssignedRow
                    drNewRow = MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned.NewDBAssignedRow

                    With drNewRow
                        .AssignedUser = intNewUserID
                        .AssignedTask = tvGeneric.Nodes(x).Tag
                        .AssignedTopic = intTopic
                        .AssignedCompleted = 0
                        .AssignedWorkCenter = m_intWorkCenter
                        .MergeID = Merge.RandomNumber()
                    End With

                    For Each Task As DataRow In MasterDBDataSet.DBTasks
                        If Task.Item("TaskTopic") = intTopic Then
                            If Task.Item("MergeID") = drNewRow.AssignedTask Then
                                Try
                                    drNewRow.AssignedHours = CInt(Task.Item("TimePerTask"))
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                    If CheckExistingAssignments(intNewUserID, drNewRow.AssignedTopic, drNewRow.AssignedTask) Then
                        MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned.Rows.Add(drNewRow)
                    End If
                    DbAssignedTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
                Else
                    ' If check box unchecked, remove from database
                    For Each OldAssigned As DataRow In MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned
                        If OldAssigned.Item("AssignedTask") = tvGeneric.Nodes(x).Tag And OldAssigned.Item("AssignedUser") = intNewUserID Then
                            Try
                                OldAssigned.Delete()
                            Catch ex As Exception

                            End Try
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DbAssignedTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
                End If
            Next

            DbAssignedTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.WriteLog("ERROR : " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: By default, a table adapter will check concurrency by validating that each field is the same as when you queried the data. My guess is that your are not calling "AcceptChanges" after the save or re-filling your data from the server. This means when you change the data and save, the next save will use the old values. Just a guess without reading too much into it.

Comment: I added AcceptChanges() to the AddRow and Delete but for some reason it doesn't effect the Database. When the form closes, nothing is added or removed from the database.Apparently since I filled the TableAdapter with the Dataset, I do not use AcceptChaneges.  The TableAdapter.Update does all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So through some reading, I was able to get a few ideas. Not answers, just ideas and I tried adding TableAdapter.Fill(Dataset.Table) after the TableAdapter.Update(Dataset.Table) and all seems to be working.

Like I said this was just an idea that seemed to work for me, not sure if this is the correct way. Would love some input on this.

This is the code I currently have working.

```
Private Sub CreateNewDataRow(intNewTreeView As Integer, intNewUserID As Integer)

        Dim tvGeneric As Windows.Forms.TreeView
        Dim intTopic As Integer

        tvGeneric = GetTreeView(intNewTreeView)
        intTopic = intNewTreeView

        Try
            ' Loop through tabs to get checked items
            For x As Integer = 0 To tvGeneric.Nodes.Count - 1
                If tvGeneric.Nodes(x).Checked = True Then
                    Dim drNewRow As MasterDBDataSet.DBAssignedRow
                    drNewRow = MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned.NewDBAssignedRow

                    With drNewRow
                        .AssignedUser = intNewUserID
                        .AssignedTask = tvGeneric.Nodes(x).Tag
                        .AssignedTopic = intTopic
                        .AssignedCompleted = 0
                        .AssignedWorkCenter = m_intWorkCenter
                        .MergeID = Merge.RandomNumber()
                    End With

                    For Each Task As DataRow In MasterDBDataSet.DBTasks
                        If Task.Item("TaskTopic") = intTopic Then
                            If Task.Item("MergeID") = drNewRow.AssignedTask Then
                                Try
                                    drNewRow.AssignedHours = CInt(Task.Item("TimePerTask"))
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                    If CheckExistingAssignments(intNewUserID, drNewRow.AssignedTopic, drNewRow.AssignedTask) Then
                        MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned.Rows.Add(drNewRow)
                    End If
                    DbAssignedTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
                    DbAssignedTableAdapter.Fill(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
                Else
                    For Each OldAssigned As DataRow In MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned
                        If OldAssigned.Item("AssignedTask") = tvGeneric.Nodes(x).Tag And OldAssigned.Item("AssignedUser") = intNewUserID Then
                            Try
                                OldAssigned.Delete()
                            Catch ex As Exception

                            End Try
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DbAssignedTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
                    DbAssignedTableAdapter.Fill(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
                End If
            Next
            DbAssignedTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.DBAssigned)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.WriteLog("ERROR : " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```